# How Do I Loop Through An Excel Spreadsheet With VBA, Paste A Value To A Website Form Then Extract The Result Back?

Tags: excel, vba, webforms

I am trying to loop through a list of names in an Excel spreadsheet using VBA and I would like to paste a surname into a text box on a webpage and then extract the returned phone number into a cell after the page has been submitted.

I can only do this one name at a time so I would like to automate this process as there are several hundreds of them. I can do the Excel looping but I don't know how to interact with the webpage.

Can anybody help, or point me in the right direction please?

Regards, Ian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should help.

As an example, I've used one of the millions of random name generators that exist on the 'Net. This code opens an IE instance, navigates to "http://www.behindthename.com/random/", inputs the surname to the form, submits the form, and returns the resulting HTML body.

I haven't parsed the result page HTML to return the actual name, as this will be different for your site, but this should help you get started.

You'll need a reference to "Microsoft Internet Controls" to access the SHDocVw.InternetExplorer object.

```
Private Function GetFromSubmittedForm(strSurname As String) As String
Dim strReturnBody As String

'Requires reference to "Microsoft Internet Controls"'
Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")


'Navigate to the URL'
IE.Navigate "http://www.behindthename.com/random/"

'No need to show the window'
IE.Visible = False

'Wait for IE to load the page'
While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


'NOTE: I have refered to each element by name, but indexes _
       can also be used: Forms("random") could be Forms(0)'


'Select the form by name:'
With IE.Document.Forms("random")

    'Reference each Input by name'
    .Surname.Value = strSurname

    'Submit the form'
    .Submit

    'Sometimes you may need to submit using _
        the name of the submit button like this:'
    '.SubmitButtonName.Click'
End With


'Wait for IE to load the new page'
While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


'Set the body of the new page to a string'
strReturnBody = IE.Document.Body.InnerHTML



'/CODE THAT ANALYSES THE BODY HTML GOES HERE'

GetFromSubmittedForm = strReturnBody

'\CODE THAT ANALYSES THE BODY HTML GOES HERE'



'Close the IE doc'
IE.Document.Close
IE.Quit
End Function
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could also consider using XMLHTTPRequest to GET/POST the form data and then extract the phone number from the response. Also, ensure you don't fall foul of any T&Cs of whichever webpage you are accessing