# Open a web page inside Excel?

Tags: internet-explorer, excel, add-in

I'm looking to develop a simple excel plugin that sends data from Excel to a web site and then displays that web site inside excel (presumably with IE).  Can anyone point me resources that might be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the built-in web query functionality in Excel - http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/get-external-data-from-a-web-page-HA010218472.aspx ?

Alternatively, [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865894/how-do-i-loop-through-an-excel-spreadsheet-with-vba-paste-a-value-to-a-website-f) may help